# Spark JDBC Oracle write using Append mode also changing the table schema if Dataframe has different schema

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, jdbc

Spark JDBC Oracle write using Append mode also changing the table schema if Dataframe has different schema. 
Is there any option to prevent spark to change oracle metadata while appending?

Comment: What if the data is different going out?

Comment: @Murali- How are you writing? Can you show code.

Comment: extra coulmn or datatype?

Comment: http://blog.kprajapati.com/Update-metadata-of-Spark-table-also-in-append-mode/

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation of spark sql data source, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html.

You can use **createTableColumnTypes** : The database column data types to use instead of the defaults, when creating the table. Data type information should be specified in the same format as CREATE TABLE columns syntax (e.g: "name CHAR(64), comments VARCHAR(1024)"). The specified types should be valid spark sql data types. This option applies only to writing.

```
// Specifying create table column data types on write
jdbcDF.write
  .option("createTableColumnTypes", "name CHAR(64), comments VARCHAR(1024)")
  .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties)
```

In example, it is using postgresql but you can use oracle jdbc driver .